# Transfer elements from one forward_list to another based on condition

Tags: c++, c++11, forward-list

I have two forward_lists: `list1` and `list2`. I'd like to iterate over the first and transfer elements to the second based on a condition. Here is an example using `forward_list<int>` that does not work but I think expresses what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    forward_list<int> list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    forward_list<int> list2;

    //Transfer elements between 2 and 5 from list1 to list2.    
    forward_list<int>::const_iterator iter_before = list1.before_begin();
    forward_list<int>::const_iterator iter = list1.begin();
    while ( iter != list1.end())
    {
        int item = *iter;
        cout << item ;
        if (2 <= item && item <= 5 )
        {
            list2.splice_after(list2.before_begin(),list1,iter_before);
            iter_before = iter;
            iter++;
            cout << "! "; // Indicates if current item is transferred.
        }
        else
        {
            iter++;
            iter_before++;
            cout << " ";
        }
    }

    cout << "\nList 1: ";
    for (auto item : list1)
    {
        cout << item << " ";
    }
    cout << "\nList 2: ";
    for (auto item : list2)
    {
        cout << item << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried resetting the `iter` and `iter_before` iterators to the beginning of `list1`, which works but transverses some `list1` elements more than once (restarts). I've also tried copying elements into `list2` first and then erasing the element on `list1`, which also works. I deem both these solutions inefficient.

Can anyone propose a more efficient one which involves just swapping the pointers at the list?

Comment: I have what I tried at the end of the post. I think the main issue is the way iterators pointing to `list1` get re-mapped to `list2` after using `splice_after()`.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is realizing that:

1. You need to obtain an iterator to the element following the one you will splice into the other list - and this must take place before the splicing. After the splice, this iterator will point to the next element to be processed.
2. After splicing, `iter_before` is still pointing right before the next element to be processed - there's no need to change it.

So, in your `if`, do instead:

```
auto iter_next = std::next(iter);
list2.splice_after(list2.before_begin(),list1,iter_before);
iter = iter_next;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6397364bc4044381).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer exactly describes the use case of STL `copy_if` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But `copy_if` doesn't do exactly what I need. I want `list1` to _not_ have the elements after transfer is complete.